# How will TRACE32 identify a coresight system in multichip mode?

Tags: arm, trace32

In a single chip system, TRACE32 could use `SYStem.DETECT DAP` to access the single root ROM table in DAP to idendify and discover the system. Then how in a multichip system?
For example, in a system of 2 chips, each of which has its own DAP and ROM table, and the two DAPs are connected in daisy chain. What will `SYStem.DETECT DAP` do? And how is the system identified?

Answer (score 2):

Select the DAP within the JTAG daisy chain by setting up the correct pre- and post-bits with the four commands
`SYStem.CONFIG.DAIRPRE`, `SYStem.CONFIG.DAIRPOST`, `SYStem.CONFIG.DADRPRE` and `SYStem.CONFIG.DADRPOST`.

To find the right values for the pre- and post-bits you can use the command `SYStem.DETECT.SHOWChain`. It opens a window which allows you to set the pre/post-bits directly from there via a context menu:
[image]

Afterwards `SYStem.DETECT.DAP` examines the DAP which is accessible with the previously defined pre/post-bits.